# How to add permission to edit only one record in own plugin

Tags: laravel, octobercms

I have own plugin where I store pubs and I want to allow pub owners to manage their site. I have no idea how to do it. How to show for specific backend user only his record?

Comment: What does your database look like? Do you have a `pubs` table? Should a user have only one pub? Should a pub belong to only one user? Or multiple?

Comment: Yes I have. Yes, only to one user. Of course me as admin should edit all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options.

1. You can add a `user_id` (or `owner_id`) column to the `pubs` table. That would mean every pub belongs to a user. You would also have to add a way to define admin users. Most simple solution would be to ad `is_admin` column to `users` table. The next simplest solution is to have a `role` column in `users` and one of the roles would be "admin" (or a number that represents "admin"). Then you would use some nice application code to make all this work.
2. You can make a `user_pub` table that would act as a link table that allows a many-to-many relationship between `users` and `pubs`. And you would have to make sure (in app code) that non-admin users don't have links to multiple pubs.

Option 2 is more flexible but if you don't need that much flexibility (now or in the future) option 1 is simpler.

Comment: And if I don't have own user plugin but want to use backend user (I create account for them in administration area). I found way how to hide some inputs and checkboxes according to permissions but I didn't find way to allow this user save only his pub. I thought I can add username to pubs table and before backend form save compare if this pub is his.

Comment: It's better to add `user_id` then `username` because comparing integers is faster, and the username could change in the future. If you can't edit the `users` table then either use option 2, or define which user (id) is admin in the code, like `const ADMIN = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a User model and a Pub model, the next thing would be to create a relationship between them. A one to many relation would fit nicely here as a user can have one or more pubs but a pub can belong to a single user.

In User model

```
public function pubs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Pub::class);
    }
```

In Pub model

```
public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

To retrieve pubs belonging to a user

```
$pubs = Auth::user()->pubs;
```

Or

```
$pubs = Pub::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

In a similar fashion you can check whether for requested pub a user is the owner by checking if the user id is the same.